# Session 'app': Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed: SHELL_UNRESPONSIVE , retry

Tags: android-studio

I am working on Android studio version 4.1.1, was just running the basic app saying "hello world " on a virtual machine.
I've been getting this SHELL_UNRESPONSIVE error once I run the program.
Here's the [error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaC2i.png)
Thank you in Advance